# How to find a good way to struct api permissions

Tags: api, permissions

## Question

I am trying to find a good way to struct the permissions of my api gateway to be accessed from a external software.

## The context

In my current company we have an API gateway.

When a user log in we send all the user permissions to the front-end service and generate all the menus and screens for the current user and what it is allowed to access.

Example:

```
{
 user: joe,
 permissions: [
  'fancyMenu',
  'anotherFancyMenu'
 ]
}
```

This approach worked really well, but right now we need to expose the API to other clients and they will access directly our endpoints.

## Problem

So previously the user who had access to fancyStuff menu need to access the endpoints x,y,z to complete a operation. Each endpoints has to check if the logged user have the fancyStuff permission.
Now we need to expose our API to other softwares.

In this example the permission fancyMenu needed to access this 3 diferent endpoints to finish the operation. Get some stuff and fancy coins to create a new fancy operation.

```
fancyMenu -> POST /fancy
fancyMenu -> GET /coins/fancy
fancyMenu -> GET /stuff
```

## Solution

That being said we created a new class on our api gateway and mapped all the menu permissions with the required endpoint.

One example is our menu fancyMenu now have a list of all endpoints that are required to do its all functionalities and we check this new class on all endpoints.

I am not sure if this is the right approach for the problem, but I couldn't find a better one.